# Can I improve the performance of Shank 2?

Tags: technical-issues, shank-2

I got Shank 2 through Humble Bundle, and the performance is pretty awful.   Have any patches been released?   Shank 1 had a similar problem that was helped by a patch posted on Icculus (but not shown on the main HB site, or the support site - or anywhere else, AFAIK).

Yes, I'm on integrated graphics, and yes, I know that what goes for Shank 1 does not necessarily go for Shank 2, but  still ...  Patch did help for 1, so I'm hopeful.

Comment: So this post has been fixed already?

Comment: (Of course, I've already tried lowering graphics settings in game and closing other programs.)

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma What do you mean?   No, to my knowledge the problem hasn't been fixed.   Did you mean my question itself?   Is something wrong with it?

Comment: Your last sentence had me thinking that you solved the problem on your own.

Comment: A while after purchasing, I saw the Humble Bundle version of Shank 2 described in the Steam forums as 'beta' ... Which is frustrating/unfair, I think, because that wasn't indicated by HB before their sale.   I don't know that this is useful in answering my question - although if it's in beta, they should release patches, right?

Comment: OK, @MarcoGeertsma - clearer now?  (Thanks for caring, BTW.)